# c++ How to instantiate System::Security::Cryptography::Aes?

Tags: visual-c++, cryptography, c++-cli, aes

I'am trying to use `Aes` abstract managed vc++ class 
I have the following code :

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Security::Cryptography;

namespace Aes_Example
{
    public ref class AesExample : public System::Security::Cryptography::Aes
    {
    public:
        AesExample():Aes(){

        }

    protected :
        ~AesExample(){
        }
    };
}
```

When I try to instantiate :

```
Aes_Example::AesExample^ mAes = gcnew Aes_Example::AesExample();
mAes->Main();
```

I got the following errors

```
error C2259: 'Aes_Example::AesExample' : cannot instantiate abstract class
1>due to following members:
1>'System::Security::Cryptography::ICryptoTransform ^System::Security::Cryptography::SymmetricAlgorithm::CreateEncryptor(cli::array<unsigned char,1> ^,cli::array<unsigned char,1> ^)' : is abstract
1>c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : see declaration of 'System::Security::Cryptography::SymmetricAlgorithm::CreateEncryptor'
1>'System::Security::Cryptography::ICryptoTransform ^System::Security::Cryptography::SymmetricAlgorithm::CreateDecryptor(cli::array<unsigned char,1> ^,cli::array<unsigned char,1> ^)' : is abstract
1>c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : see declaration of 'System::Security::Cryptography::SymmetricAlgorithm::CreateDecryptor'
1>'void System::Security::Cryptography::SymmetricAlgorithm::GenerateKey(void)' : is abstract
1>c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : see declaration of 'System::Security::Cryptography::SymmetricAlgorithm::GenerateKey'
1>'void System::Security::Cryptography::SymmetricAlgorithm::GenerateIV(void)' : is abstract
1>c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : see declaration of 'System::Security::Cryptography::SymmetricAlgorithm::GenerateIV'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[System.Security.Cryptography.Aes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx) is abstract.

To create its instances use one of its [Create() static methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes.create(v=vs.110).aspx).

Or just use [AesManaged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

There's no point to inherit from `Aes` (you'd have to implement  `CreateDecryptor`, `CreateEncryptor`, `GenerateIV`, and `GenerateKey` methods of [SymmetricAlgorithm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: AesManaged doesn't exist for C++, and SymmetricAlgorithm got the same status as Aes

Comment: @نجييبفاضل OK, so what about `Aes::Create()`?

Comment: Thanks Anton for your help, I changed my mind and used AesManaged c# example converted to c++, before I didn't know about the Hint given by @hans-passant (Thanks Hans) (Adding System.Core), finally no need to use Aes.